# Wired Network (eth0) disappears on a Lenovo Z570

Tags: 12.04, ethernet

I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 yesterday. I am running a BSNL Broadband DSL conenction. The wired network suddenly dissapears and the computer stops detecting the ethernet card after sometime. However, after rebooting, it again becomes alright.

```
$ lspci | grep Ethernet 
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

Specs:

- Lenovo Ideapad Z570
- Intel i5 2nd Gen. processor
- 3 GB RAM

Comment: So what's the problem here?

Comment: The wired network keeps disappearing. I think its a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This solved the problem for me. All configuration files were rewritten including the ones for network-manager. I must add that I have a Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG on a Dell XPS M1530.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your network driver .Ubuntu default network drivers are not supporting.
you can fix this by installing a network driver ."compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc" tis will solve the problem.
[read this post.it will help you to install the driver](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1113683-ubuntu-doesnt-see-my-nic-card/)